# tail bounds for sum of n iid variables divided by power of n

Tags: measure-concentration, large-deviations

Let $X_i, 1\leq i\leq n$ be i.i.d. random variables with finite moments. Then $Y_n :=\frac{1}{n^{1+\delta}}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i$ goes to 0 almost surely for any $\delta >0$. What are some good non-asymptotic tail bounds for $Y_n$, without assuming that $X_i$'s are subexponential?

(Berry-Esseen is one option that I know of.)